# SQL Query help WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, group-by

I have a SQL query and am getting an error when adding the `where` clause. It works fine without the where clause.

```
SELECT t.*, n.Caption, n.Description
FROM (
    SELECT NodeID
        , COUNT(DISTINCT CPUIndex) AS "Number of CPU"
        , COUNT(DISTINCT CPUIndex)/8 AS "Number of Cores"
    FROM CPUMultiLoad_Detail AS cpu WITH (NOLOCK)
    --WHERE N.Description LIKE '%T7%'
    GROUP BY NodeID
) AS T
INNER JOIN NodesData AS N ON T.NodeID = n.NodeID
```

But with the `where` clause I get the following error:

> The multi-part identifier "N.Description" could not be bound.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I added the sql-server tag to your question, since the error message - and the use of `with(nolock)` - tends to indicate that this is the database that you are running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column that you want to filter on belongs to table `NodesData`, which is not available in the subquery. You need to move the filtering to the outer query instead:

```
select t.*, n.caption, n.description
from (
    select 
        nodeid, 
        count(distinct cpuindex) as number_of_cpu, 
        count(distinct cpuindex)/8 as number_of_cores
    from CPUMultiLoad_Detail
    group by nodeid
) as t
inner join NodesData as n on t.nodeid = n.nodeid
where n.description like '%t7%'
```

Side notes:

- `with(nolock)` is generally not needed, or should be be used blindly - I removed it
- in general, it is better to use identifiers that do not require quoting